# IOS10 above system, mixed content,background-image inserted picture does not display

Tags: ios, geolocation, mixed-content

IOS10 above system, mixed content（html by https,img by http）, when the call of geolocation.getCurrentPosition, background-image inserted picture does not display

```
<pre>
<div id="aaa" style="background-image:url(http://xxx.jpg);height:200px;"></div>
<script>
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
</script>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct behaviour. On https page all http content must not be shown as it is insecure. Even if it is inserted through JS. Browser simply doesn't make request for such content.